# How can I inject class-specific logger using LightInject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

Many logging frameworks provide class-specific loggers:

NLog:  `Logger.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass).Name)`

Serilog:  `Log.Logger.ForContext<MyClass>()`

To be able to inject these class specific loggers, one would do something like this in Ninject:

```
        Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(context =>
        {
            var typeForLogger = context.Request.Target != null ? context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType : context.Request.Service;
            return context.Kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>().GetLogger(typeForLogger);
        });
```

where `context.Request.Target` provides the type that will receive the injection.

I can't find any way to do the same using LightInject; is this feature not supported (yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out someone else had the same problem: https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/issues/186

Basically, the solution is to use a logger class that takes in the classname as a constructor parameter:

```
public interface ILog
{
    void Debug(string message, params object[] args);
}

public class SeriLogger : ILog
{
    static SeriLogger ()
    {
        LoggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Trace();
    }

    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private static readonly LoggerConfiguration LoggerConfig;

    public SeriLogger(Type type)
    {
        logger = LoggerConfig.CreateLogger().ForContext(type);
    }

    public void Debug(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        logger.Debug(message, args);
    }
}
```

And then register the logger using `RegisterConstructorDependency`:

```
// Wherever you register your types
container.RegisterConstructorDependency<ILog>((factory, info) => new SeriLogger(info.Member.DeclaringType));
```